# How to integrate iCloud sync with Core Data in Swift 3.0 ios 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I have tried many tutorials but not not able to find in latest swift version. Is there any tutorial in Swift 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this http://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/06/17/the-deprecation-of-icloud-core-data/.  As this article summarizes, Apple's view on Core Data & iCloud sync is uncertain (perhaps)

Then have a look at this: http://www.ensembles.io

Comment: It's pretty certain. It's deprecated, so new code should avoid it. But it still works, so existing apps won't break (yet).